# Как правильно в nodejs (express-mongoose) передавать данные в поле select

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, node.js

Только недавно начал изучать node js. Помогите решить такую задачу:
Есть к примеру таблицы валюта и кошельки, для кошелька указано поле с типов "Валюта".
Нужно что бы при редактировании кошелька, в поле валюта можно было выбрать данные только с таблицы "Валюта". Как это делать в общем, я понимаю (найти все валюты Currency.find({},...) и передать в ejs). Проблема в том что таких таблиц и полей много, поэтому хотелось бы знать как это правильно делается?
Вот как сейчас сделано у меня, но мне кажется что здесь сам подход не правильный, плюс я не знаю как в Middleware - selectInputs передать переменную с нужными мне настройками под каждую страницу "addPurse":
Таблица валюты:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schemaCurrency = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    code: String,
    course: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Currency", schemaCurrency);
```

Таблица кошельки:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schemaPurse = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    currency: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Object,
            ref: "Currency"
        },
        name: String
    },
    comment: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Purse", schemaPurse);
```

При переходе на страницу с добавлением кошелька:

```
router.get('/purses/add', selectInputs, function(req,res,next){
...
});
```

Middleware - selectInputs

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    var currentPage = require('./config.json')["addPurse"];

    if(!currentPage){return}

    var inputs = currentPage.inputs;


    inputs.forEach(function(input){
        var model = require(input.model);
        model.find({}, function(err, allData){
            if(err){
                next(err);
            } else {
                res.locals[input.name] = allData;
            }
        });
    });

    next();

}
```

./config.json

```
{
  "addPurse":{
    "inputs": [
      {"name":"currencies", "model":"../../models/currency"}
    ]
  }
}
```

поле "Валюта" в add.ejs

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="currency" required>
                <% currencies.forEach(function(currency){ %>
                    <option value="<%= currency._id %>"><%= currency.name %></option>
                <% }) %>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Покажите полностью задачу или опишите подробнее, не понятно как выглядит таблица и что нужно выводить.

Comment: как таковой задачи нету, я для себя ее сам составил (пишу приложение с помощью которого можно будет делать приход и расход денег). P.S. Более подробно расписал вопрос.